# Recursion -- how to do an action only at the end

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures

I have a binary search tree where each node (`GameEntry` class) represents one "game play" (a name/score pair). The tree is organized by name (not score). I'm trying to write a method for the tree to print a list of its top ten scores (with the corresponding name). I thought of traversing the tree recursively, putting a node in an array (`ScoreBoard` class) if (and only if) it's a high score. It works, except my problem was that the scoreboard would print every step of the way in the recursion.

```
public void printTopTen()
{
    ScoreBoard board = new ScoreBoard(10); // new scoreboard with capacity of 10
    printTopTenRecur(this.root, board);
}

// Auxillary method for printTopTen()
private void printTopTenRecur(GameEntry node, ScoreBoard board)
{
    if (node == null)
        {
            return;
        }
    printTopTenRecur(node.getLeft(), board);
    board.add(node); // adds the node to the scoreboard if it's a high score
    System.out.println(board);
    printTopTenRecur(node.getRight(), board);
}
```

The only thing I could think of was to create an attribute (called `board`) on the class and then print out the attribute after the recursion is done. But I'm getting the compile time error `void cannot be converted to String`. I'm not sure how else to do it.

```
public String printTopTen()
{
    ScoreBoard board = new ScoreBoard(10); // new scoreboard with capacity of 10
    printTopTenRecur(this.root, board);
    return System.out.println(this.board);
}

// Auxillary method for printTopTen()
private void printTopTenRecur(GameEntry node, ScoreBoard board)
{
    if (node == null)
        {
            return;
        }
    printTopTenRecur(node.getLeft(), board);
    board.add(node); // adds the node to the score board if it's a high score
    this.board = board; // assign local board to the board on the tree
    printTopTenRecur(node.getRight(), board);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I'm getting the compile time error void cannot be converted to String

You are getting that error because `System.out.println(this.board);` is not a `String` and have stated that `printTopTen` should return a `String`.

If all that you want to do is printing the board at the end of the recursion you could do this:

```
public void printTopTen()
{
    ScoreBoard board = new ScoreBoard(10); // new scoreboard with capacity of 10
    printTopTenRecur(this.root, board);
    System.out.println(this.board);
}
```

This will show whatever you have defined in the `toString` method of the `ScoreBoard` class.

If what you want to do is return the `String` you can do it like this:

```
public String printTopTen()
{
   ScoreBoard board = new ScoreBoard(10); // new scoreboard with capacity of 10
   printTopTenRecur(this.root, board);
   return this.board.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion works. I realize now that `println` returns void! After your correction, I also tried `return this.board.toString()`. It compiles, but I get the runtime error NoSuchMethodError. Confused again.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a great fun of recursion, especially not it java, the main reason is that you risk a stack overflow if you go too deep. Other languages deals with this problem allowing tail calls to be implicitly transformed into a while loop (like scala for example).

That being said, recursion without return value sounds really odd to me, while the suggestion of moondaisy addresses your problem I would rather return the score instead of relying on a field.

```
private ScoreBoard printTopTenRecur(GameEntry node, ScoreBoard board){
  if(node == null )
    return board;

  board.add(node);
  ScoreBoard leftBoard = printTopTenRecur(node.getLeft(), board);
  ScoreBoard rightBoard = printTopTenRecur(node.getRight(), leftBoard);

  return rightBoard;
}

public void printTopTen(){
    ScoreBoard board = new ScoreBoard(10); // new scoreboard with capacity of 10
    // No need to return anything if you want to just print the result
    System.out.println(printTopTenRecur(this.root, board));
}
```

*A side note*:
`ScoreBoard leftBoard = printTopTenRecur(...)` is pretty useless like that, board is mutable so passing it sufficient.

When I think *recursive* I also think *immutable*, so I would rather have liked a `ScoreBoard newBoard = board.update(node);` returning a new updated ScoreBoard, like this:

```
  ScoreBoard currentBoard = board.update(node);
  ScoreBoard leftBoard = printTopTenRecur(node.getLeft(), currentBoard);
  ScoreBoard rightBoard = printTopTenRecur(node.getRight(), leftBoard);
```

This way printTopTenRecur is a function without side effects, so a proper function.

Comment: Thank you for your different perspective, which gives me lots to think about.